# Ad displayed by Google Mobile Ads SDK dismisses when app goes to background

Tags: ios, swift, admob

Here is the code which presents reward based video on any view controller:

```
GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: vc)
```

Its successfully shows the video, but when the app enters background and comes to foreground, the ad dismisses itself and `rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose` fires.

Is it normal behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, this is intended behavior.**

It's there to prevent getting rewards for a video the user is not even watching.

For more information, check out [the documentation of `GADRewardBasedVideoAd`.](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/adx/ios/api/reference/Classes/GADRewardBasedVideoAd)

Comment: Thanks. and same for GADInterstitial?

Comment: @NarekSimonyan Yes, exactly.